# objective-c interface - declaring variable vs just property?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In Obj-c when declaring a variable within @interface

> @interface: NSObject{
>   MyObject* myObject}
>
> @property (unsafe, nonatomic) MyObject* myObject;

Vs. Only declare it as a property

> @interface: NSObject{}
>
> @property (unsafe, nonatomic) MyObject* myObject;
>   @end

Not declare any var here?

Regards
Christian

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`@property` defines an interface, not an implementation. In your case, you're defining a readwrite property. This means that you're promising to implement `-myObject` and `-setMyObject:`. This has nothing to do with ivars.

Now, the most common way to implement those methods is by having them be backed by an ivar. As a convenience, ObjC lets you automatically generate the required methods with an ivar store using `@synthesize myObject=myObject_;` This says "create the required methods for the property `myObject` using an automatically created ivar called `myObject_`." The ivar `myObject_` is a real ivar, and you can access it normally (though you generally shouldn't; you should use accessors).

Instead of using `@synthesize`, you could just implement `-myObject` and `-setMyObject:`. You could even use `@dynamic myObject;` to tell the compiler "don't worry about the implementations for this property; it'll be handled correctly at runtime."

There are a few differences between `@property` and just declaring methods, but in principle, this line:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) MyObject* myObject;
```

is conceptually the same as this:

```
- (MyObject *)myObject;
- (void)setMyObject:(MyObject *)anObject;
```

Declaring the ivar yourself has no real impact here. You still need to implement the methods somehow. If your named ivar is the same as the ivar `@synthesize` is using, then `@synthesize` just won't create a new ivar.

As a matter of practice, I discourage people from declaring ivars anymore. I recommend just using public and private properties with `@synthesize` to create any needed ivars. If you must have a manual ivar for some reason, then I recommend declaring them in the `@implementation` block rather than the `@interface`.

Answer (score 9):

Skipping declaring the ivar is perfectly fine--but you will not be able to see the ivar's value in the Xcode IDE. One day Apple may fix this.

You will be able to "po" the ivar to inspect it in GDB or lldb.

Comment: +1 for that -- I've been swearing at the debugger a lot lately, didn't occur to me that declaring the ivar would make my stuff visible to the debugger!

Comment: Please file a bug report with Apple: bugreport.apple.com