# How to simulate protected properties and methods in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5, protected

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Protected methods in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725857/protected-methods-in-objective-c)

The way to declare private properties is simple.

You declare that in extension that's declared in .m files.

Say I want to declare protected properties and access it from the class and subclass.

This is what I tried:

```
//
//  BGGoogleMap+protected.h
//
//

#import "BGGoogleMap.h"

@interface BGGoogleMap ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString * protectedHello;
@end
```

That one is compile. Then I added:

```
#import "BGGoogleMap+protected.h"

@implementation BGGoogleMap ()

-(NSString *) protectedHello
{
    return _
}

@end
```

Problem starts. I can't implement class extension outside the original .m files it seems. Xcode will demand something inside that bracket.

If I do

```
#import "BGGoogleMap+protected.h"

@implementation BGGoogleMap (protected)

-(NSString *) protectedHello
{
    return _
}

@end
```

I cannot access the ivar of _protectedHello declared in BGGoogleMap+protected.h

Of course I can use regular category rather than extension, but that means I can't have protected properties.

So what should I do?

Comment: Rob wrote an awesome answer not available on the other question. Also this question is about simulation rather than actual protected variable, which is impossible to implement in objective-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW2) says this:

> Class extensions are like anonymous categories, except that the methods they declare must be implemented in the main `@implementation` block for the corresponding class.

So you could just implement your class extension's methods in the class's main `@implementation`.  That is the simplest solution.

A more complicated solution is to declare your “protected” messages and properties in a category, and declare any instance variables for that category in a class extension.  Here's the category:

#### `BGGoogleMap+protected.h`

```
#import "BGGoogleMap.h"

@interface BGGoogleMap (protected)

@property (nonatomic) NSString * protectedHello;

@end
```

Since a category cannot add an instance variable to hold `protectedHello`, we need a class extension also:

#### `BGGoogleMap_protectedInstanceVariables.h'

```
#import "BGGoogleMap.h"

@interface BGGoogleMap () {
    NSString *_protectedHello;
}
@end
```

We need to include the class extension in the main `@implementation` file so that the compiler will emit the instance variable in the `.o` file:

#### `BGGoogleMap.m`

```
#import "BGGoogleMap.h"
#import "BGGoogleMap_protectedInstanceVariables.h"

@implementation BGGoogleMap

...
```

And we need to include the class extension in the category `@implementation` file so that the category methods can access the instance variables.  Since we declared the `protectedHello` property in a category, the compiler will *not* synthesize the setter and getter method.  We have to write them by hand:

#### `BGGoogleMap+protected.m`

```
#import "BGGoogleMap+protected.h"

@implementation BGGoogleMap (protected)

- (void)setProtectedHello:(NSString *)newValue {
    _protectedHello = newValue; // assuming ARC
}

- (NSString *)protectedHello {
    return _protectedHello;
}

@end
```

Subclasses should import `BGGoogleMap+protected.h` to be able to use the `protectedHello` property.  They should not import `BGGoogleMap_protectedInstanceVariables.h` because the instance variables should be treated as private to the base class.  If you ship a static library without source code, and you want users of the library to be able to subclass `BGGoogleMap`, ship the `BGGoogleMap.h` and `BGGoogleMap+protected.h` headers, but don't ship the `BGGoogleMap_protectedInstanceVariables.h` header.

Comment: Rob, I think BGGoogleMap+protected.h alone will generate compile error. Did you try this? Also, an answer here seems to work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725857/protected-methods-in-objective-c it's awkward due to using protocol too.

Comment: No the answer over there doesn't involve properties at all and no wonder get only 2 upvotes.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe you're correct. I'll check.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking about.  If you're getting a compile error, copy the error message and post it.

Comment: I am not sure we can declare @property in category, which was the whole problem. However, then I realized that you take care of that by declaring the iVar in extension.

Comment: Now here is the issue, you declare BGGoogleMap_protectedInstanceVariables.h. That means all other ivar and private properties will be in BGGoogleMap_protectedInstanceVariables.h too right? Including those who I don't plan to share with my subclasses. Not like we can create 2 extensions can we?

Comment: "@property defines an interface, not an implementation. In your case, you're defining a readwrite property. This means that you're promising to implement -myObject and -setMyObject:. This has nothing to do with ivars." See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065417/objective-c-interface-declaring-variable-vs-just-property

Comment: Quite clever, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I wish I could tell you otherwise but you just can't. See this question for more information: [Protected methods in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725857/protected-methods-in-objective-c).

Comment: Thanks you pointed to the one right answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, what you want to do? Something Hacking or Cracking of Data Abstraction out of OOPS concept?

Extensions are used to add properties. You have successfully added private property as in

```
#import "BGGoogleMap.h"

@interface BGGoogleMap ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString * protectedHello;
@end
```

What are you doing in this ?

```
#import "BGGoogleMap+protected.h"

@implementation BGGoogleMap ()

-(NSString *) protectedHello
{
    return _
}

@end
```

You have extended a class, now you are again implementing same class !!! Twice!!! And category only comes with .h file. I guess you are creating yourself a .m file, that not acceptable.

Private properties cant be accessed outside the class, it can be accessed only from the base class or subclass. That is what the error is.

```
I can't implement class extension outside the original .m files it seems.
```

Yes this is abstraction and data hiding of Objective-c !!!

Comment: "Private properties cant be accessed outside the class, it can be accessed only from the base class or subclass." Don't know about properties, but this is not true for methods, which is what he wants...

Comment: He is using properties... kindly check to access the property he tried to override it by making setters and getters. So his main idea was wrong, thats why his question is closed.