# About .h and .m files (how to manage)

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hey experienced programmers!

Id like to ask you something about clean code :)

Id like to keep my code clean and make it nice, so thats my questions:

1)Where should I put #imports?
My principles: (and i dont think that they are good)

- #import Frameworks should be always in .h
- #import .h files should be always in .m
- .h files should have only @class, not imports (excluding frameworks like UIKit, etc)
- Delegates should be in .m

  ```
  @interface ViewController() <UIAlertViewDelegate> 
  @end
  ```

2)Where should I put my instance variables?

- Private and Protected variables must be in .m
- Public must be in .h

3)Where should I put my methods?

- Public in .h
- Private in .m
  (And yeah I know that my "Private methods" are not really private, just hidden)

(btw thats pretty obvious)

4)What about #defines?

- Global - always in .h
- Used only in that class - always in .m

5)Where should I put NSNotification global identifiers and how to organize them

- #define NSNotificationDataSourceDidLoadData @"NSNotificationDataSourceDidLoadData" in .h file in the class that will send this notification

But ....

- Apple has a lot of private things in .h file
- In most cases my .h files are just.. EMPTY :)

A year ago I had another situation - **everything** was in .h, but I think it is bad also

What to do? What principles are you using?
Thank you!

Thats a questions about coding style, not about "how to make it compilable"

Comment: This is overly broad.  Perhaps you could focus on a specific aspect, rather than laying down 12 sub-questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I do it:

- The usual `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` or `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` go into the .pch file. No header or implementation file is doing these imports again (makes sharing code between iOS and Mac OS X a tiny bit easier).
- In .h files:

  - Other .h files are only imported if absolutely necessary, for example because they define types other than classes (enums, structs, everything with a typedef) which are then used in the current .h file.
  - Classes are forward declared (`@class Foo;`) to avoid pulling in other .h files.
  - Interfaces only contain stuff that other classes may access! No private stuff here!
- In .m files:

  - Include all the .h files you need. But not more ;-)
  - Private instance variables and properties are defined in a class extension (`@interface Foo ()`).
  - Private methods don't need to be "forward declared" any more, so don't do that.

In the rare case that a class has some stuff that a few classes should access but the "normal" users shouldn't, I create `foo_protected.h` headers with a class category that defines the "protected" methods.

A word on `#define`s: avoid them if possible. Use `const` variables or `enum`s instead if possible, as the additional type information can help the compiler catch more mistakes this way. For example, using `enum`s has the nice advantage that you get a warning if you've got a `switch` but didn't handle all the values of the `enum`. If you add a new value you'll get warnings everywhere you forgot to handle them which is something you don't get with `#define`s.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the private method/function forward declaration thing; I'd forgotten about that

Comment: @DarkDust Hi, I am a bit late here. But can you please cite an example in code how a class category defining "protected" can be achieved via `foo_protected.h`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Unheilig: See [How to simulate protected properties and methods in objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637944/how-to-simulate-protected-properties-and-methods-in-objective-c).

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I think the answer is pretty simple. Now that instance variables can be declared in the `@implementation`, and properties and protocol adoptions can be declared in a class extension in the *.m* file, I don't put *anything* in a *.h* file that I don't absolute *have* to put there.

Answer (score 2):

> import Frameworks should be always in .h

No, why?

> import .h files should be always in .m

That's pretty vague. And what if you need to import something in a header file? You want to subclass a class, what you do? `#import "SomeClass.h"` in the header.

> .h files should have only @class, not imports (excluding frameworks like UIKit, etc)

Brainless. (Sorry, it really is. See the reasoning above.)

> 2)Where should I put my instance variables?

Since other classes really aren't supposed to access ivars (i. e. it is recommended not to make your ivars `public`), you can put them anywhere: the header is fine (and it's useful for compatibility with the v1.0 fragile runtime API), but you can get away with placing everything in the class extension as well.

> 3)Where should I put my methods?

You got this one right, pretty much.

> 4)What about #defines?

This is good too, as far as I'm concerned. Basically, put defines and enums to the place where they need to be visible.

> Apple has a lot of private things in .h file
>   In most cases my .h files are just.. EMPTY :)

Well, even Apple isn't very consistent with their style. Be consistent.

Empty headers? If you don't need a header, don't use one. Use headers to provide interface for your classes, functions and type declarations.